# RMI: много запросов, одни данные

Tags: rmi, client, java, сервер

Есть сервер, у сервера 2 метода: заменить какие-то данные в массиве/прочитать какие-то данные в массиве. Массив этот лежит в памяти сервера. К нему подключаются одновременно несколько [1-∞] клиентов и в несколько [1-∞] потоков начинают дёргать эти методы. Что произойдёт в этом случае? Всё крякнется? Клиенты будут ловить ошибки? RMI умный и ничего не  сломается, просто увеличится время доступа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от того, какова модель обраюотки запросов сервера.

Если на каждое соединение создается отдельный поток для обработки запросов, то в зависимости от возможностей сервера вы рано или поздно упретесь в невозможноть создания нового потока (причины могут быть разные, от нехватки памяти, потокам она тоже нужна, до невозможности ОС создать новый поток (закончидись дескрипторы и исчерпан лимит потоков)).

Обычная практика, создавать пул потоков, и обламывать входящие запросы, если пул истощен. В любом случае при увеличениии кол-ва потоков увеличится и время обработки запросов из-за постоянного переключения контекстов потоков.

Если же сервер использует неблокирующий ввод вывод, то в одном потоке можно обрабатывать множестов соединений. Здесь пределом скорее всего будет именно кол-во соединений (и соответственно сокетов), которые может выдержать сервер.

Время обработки запросов также будет увеличиваться с ростом кол-ва соединений, потому что теперь основной поток должен постоянно между ними переключаться и обрабатывать данные.

Смешанная модель, когда есть несколько потоков, которые могут обрабатывать сразу множество соединений, страдает недостатками обеих моделей. Такова жизнь, ресурсы ограничены.

PS: RMI не умный. Это всего лишь аббревиатура ;) Думать должен разработчик.

Comment: Так, всё, что я тут накомментировал было неверно, попытка номер 2:
@a_gura, получается, это от меня зависит, что и как будет? Сейчас у меня данные изменяются сразу же в методе, который я вызываю клиентом. А я могу, например, завести очередь из комманд, и завести один процесс, который будет эти команды выполнять. Или я могу при каждом вызове метода создавать новый поток, который будет выполнять мои действия. Я правильно понял эти модели?

Comment: И сразу ещё один вопрос: какие проблемы могут возникнуть, если я оставлю всё как есть? 
Например сейчас мой метод выглядит вот так:

    public void addAmount(Integer id, Long value) throws RemoteException {
        requestsCount++;
        if (data.containsKey(id)) {
            data.put(id, data.get(id) + value);
        } else {
            data.put(id, value);
        }
    }

Comment: И вот ещё такая мысль. Если, как я написал
> Или я могу при каждом вызове метода создавать новый поток, который будет выполнять мои действия.
то как тогда, например, вот этот метод вернёт нужное мне значение?
    public Long getAmount(Integer id) throws RemoteException {
        requestsCount++;
        if (data.containsKey(id)) {
            return data.get(id);
        } else {
            return (long) 0;
        }
    }

Comment: А может мне просто объявить эти методы как synchronized?
Ой чё-то я разп***елся... Я вроде вчера тестил сервер, дёргал эти методы с двух двухъядерных компов в ~2к потоков, вроде ничего не упало, хотя, конечно я не смог проверить, все ли вызовы успешно завершились без потери данных

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемому [@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura) большое спасибо за ответ, он во многом помог мне разобраться.
А для меня выход из ситуации разрешился сначала благодаря словам Thread-safety, а затем ConcurrentMap и AtomicLong.